# Django Celery send register email do not work

Tags: python, django, celery

I am learning Celery. In my website, I let people register an account. Once they create a new account, it will automatically send an activation email to their user email address.

Everything works well but now I want to use Celery to send the email asynchronously.

I use RabbitMQ as broker, version 3.1.5 and Celery 3.1.7 (the latest version), as they say this version does not need djcelery. So all I need is just to install Celery.

I followed the instruction as celery its website, Configurate my django.

```
proj
  --proj/celery.py
```

Here is my **celery.py**:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os

from celery import Celery

from django.conf import settings

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings')

app = Celery('proj')

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request:{0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

And this is the **tasks.py** that I put in my app folder:

```
proj
 ---proj/celery.py
 ---app/tasks.py
```

**tasks.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from celery.decorators import task

@task()
def user_send_activation_email(user):
    user.send_activation_email()
```

I added the `send_activation_email` function to user models, so user can send the email.

This is my **views.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, redirect,render
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponse,HttpResponseRedirect,Http404
from django.template import RequestContext
from app.accounts.forms import SignupForm
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from app.sns_utils import generate_sha1 
from app.tasks import user_send_activation_email 

def signup(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=SignupForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            UserModel=get_user_model()
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
             user=UserModel.objects.create_user(username=username,email=email,password=password)
            user.activation_key = generate_sha1(username)
            user.save()
            user_send_activation_email.delay(user=user)


            return redirect('/')
```

And here is how I configured Celery in **settings.py**:

```
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//'

CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//'

CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

everything just follow celery its website say.

Once I `manage.py runserver`, in the signup page, I register a new account with username  `vmuser630`, and it shows this error:

```
EncodeError at /accounts/signup/
<MyUser: vmuser630> is not JSON serializable
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/accounts/signup/
Django Version: 1.6
Exception Type: EncodeError
Exception Value:    
<MyUser: vmuser630> is not JSON serializable
Exception Location: C:\Python33\lib\json\encoder.py in default, line 173
Python Executable:  C:\Python33\python.exe
Python Version: 3.3.2
```

If I remove this from **settings.py**:

```
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

and try again `manage.py runserver`, I'm just redirected to the '/' page. The new account is in the database, but I did not get the activation email.

It looks like the send email task has just been passed, nothing happened.

When i change the send email function back to:

```
user.send_activation_email()
```

it means I do not user celery, it works, I can get the activation email.

Why does it show the error **not  JSON serializable**?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Celery need to serialize the arguments for a task. Here, `user` is not serializable, but you can replace it with its ID:

In **tasks.py**:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from celery.decorators import task
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

@task()
def user_send_activation_email(user_id):
    user = get_user_model().objects.get(pk=user_id)
    user.send_activation_email()
```

Then call it from **views.py** using:

```
user_send_activation_email.delay(user_id=user.pk)
```

Comment: hi
i change code as you say,now it not show error not JSON serializable.
but i still can not get the activate email .and i add print(33) to that tasks.py . nothing happen ,looks like the task not run ,just pass.

Comment: Did you restart the Celery worker? Do you see pending messages in RabbitMQ? Use e.g. `rabbitmqadmin list queues messages`, number of messages should be zero. What happens if you run the command from `python manage.py shell`, e.g. `from app.tasks import user_send_activation_email; user_send_activation_email.delay(user_id=some_user_id)`? You should also have some log files created by the worker, those may help you debugging.

Comment: hi
i just do what you said.
manage.py shell then it show
AsyncResult:ad0a8326-f6ed-44bc-a9fe-7ae6c2f14b38
and my RabbitMQ Queres,
name :  celery,
status : idle,
Message readlly : 18 ,
you said it should be zero.
i think the problem is RabbitMQ,i do not know much about RabbitMQ,i just install follow its tutorial.how can i make the message run

Comment: You need to start a Celery worker which will consume messages from RabbitMQ and execute the tasks. Check the [documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#starting-the-worker), this should be something like `celery --app=proj/celery worker -l info`.

Comment: hi
as my project called mysns ,and i create the app called sns,so i type
celery --sns=mysns worker -1 info
then it show 'celery-script.py:error:no such option -1 '

Comment: The option name is `--app`, do not change it. Put the path to your `celery.py` configuration file after the `=`. The next option is `-l` with the *letter* `l`, not the *number* `1`. Try `celery --app=sns/celery -l info` from the `mysns` directory for example.

Comment: hi
i have to say ,thank you Nicolas ,i make it work now .
i open another commend.exe (i use windows system ) and type 'celery worker --app=mysns' then i create a new user in my signup page ,this time i get the activate email.

thank you very much !

Comment: hi
i think it is still the problem.it just work once ,all the messages in RabbitMQ gone ,and now i try it again ,it do not work again.the the message leave in RabbitMQ,every time ,i register an new account ,RabbitMQ add a new message .but i do start celery worker,it show "Task sns.tasks.user_send_activation_email[c2a7ad53-bada-4e20-a67d-a76d9128e15e] succeeded in 1.91899999994412s:None "

Comment: finally ,i make it work,i mean i get the activation email.this is how i do.open another commend.exe ,go to the folder where the project is ,(my project called mysns)type " celery --app=mysns works -l info" ,then it works now .merci beaucoup Nicolas

Answer (score 8):

see [setting-task_serializer](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#std:setting-task_serializer), you can set CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'pickle' in celery conf.

Comment: Thanks.
for advantages and disadvantages from docs: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#calling-serializers