# At what point does celery store result?

Tags: python, django, numpy, redis, celery

I am using celery + redis for tasks in Django web app. The problem is that I don't know at what point does celery store it's task result as JSON object into DB. Afterwards an issue is raised because it cannot store np array as JSON.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import dok_matrix


@shared_task(name="run_shortest_path_on_warehouse")
def run_shortest_path_on_warehouse(adjacency_matrix):
    sparse_matrix = dok_matrix(adjacency_matrix)
    dist_matrix = dijkstra_algorithm(sparse_matrix).tolist()
    return {'optimal_distance_matrix': dist_matrix}
```

Celery can't store the result, because of this exception:

```
{"exc_type": "EncodeError", "exc_message": ["TypeError(\"Object of type 'ndarray' is not JSON serializable\",)"], "exc_module":    "kombu.exceptions"}
```

I know that numpy array isn't simply JSON serializable. That's why I used `.tolist` method in defining the `dist_matrix` variable.

The question is, at what point does celery store it's variable and how can I store info from numpy array as task result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Celery need to serialize the arguments for a task. hope this same issue helps:
[Django Celery send register email do not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20826725/django-celery-send-register-email-do-not-work)

Comment: I don't know whether this was the issue, but it does work.

I recommend to all to restart their celery worker, because it may be the cause as well.